# How can the entry be connected to method

Tags: python, tkinter

as a practice, I am trying to make the code for gui, and implemted a method named as get_me() to search. In this code, I imported wikipedia, and tried to search about google, and i am supposed to get the information about google. but I got some error saying "entry is not defined" which is located on line 34

```
import tkinter as tk
import os, sys
import wikipedia

class GuiTest():
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('CHOI')
        frame3 = tk.Frame(root)
        label1=tk.Label(frame3,text='please enter your name')
        entry = tk.Entry(frame3)
        label1.pack(padx=5, pady=5,expand=True, fill='both',side='left')
        entry.pack(padx=5, pady=5,expand=True, fill='both',side='left')
        btn1=tk.Button(frame3, text = 'search',command=self.get_me)
        btn1.pack(padx=6, pady=6,expand=True, fill='both', side='right')
        frame3.pack(padx=5,pady=5, expand=True, fill='both')
        frame1=tk.Frame(root)
        btn2=tk.Button(frame1,text='exit',command = self.exit)
        btn2.pack(padx=7, pady=7, fill='both', side='bottom')
        frame1.pack(padx=7, pady=7, fill='both')
        frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
        scroll=tk.Scrollbar(frame2)
        scroll.pack(side='right', fill='both')
        answer = tk.Text(frame2, width=30, height=10, yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
        scroll.config(command=answer.yview)
        answer.pack(side='bottom')
        
        frame2.pack()

        root.mainloop()
    def exit(self):
        sys.exit(0)
        
    def get_me(self):
        entry_value = entry.get()
        answer_value = wikipedia.summary(entry_value)
        
        answer.insert(INSERT, answer_value)
    


if __name__=="__main__":
    root =tk.Tk()
    bapp = GuiTest(root)
    bapp.mainloop
```

Comment: `entry` was a local variable in `__init__()`; it *doesn't exist* when you try to access it in `get_me()`.  Use `self.entry` instead.

Comment: If you want a widget to be available in all methods of a class, you should make them global within the class by making them an attribute of self: `self.entry = Entry(...`. This will create the attribute `.entry` to the class that can be accessed in all methods. So, instead of `entry.get()` you can then write `self.entry.get()` and get the value of this Entry widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `entry` to `self.entry` in `__init__` function

```py
self.entry = tk.Entry(frame3)

#do self.entry wherever entry was there
#and then in get_me() function do self.entry

entry_value = self.entry.get()
```